# Android x86 6.0 R3 just showing Android logo after booting up from Grub2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

really appreciate if someone can assist me if I did anything wrong on this one.. first the specs:

1. Pipo X7 Intel Atom Z3735F box, 2gb RAM, 32GB eMMc
2. Ubuntu Mate 18.04 x64
3. Android x86 6.0 R3 x86_64

So I have first installed Ubuntu, on the internal SD card. Using automatic Ubuntu partitioning, 2 partitions were created on SD mmcblk1, mmcblk1p1 for EFI, and mmcblk1p2 for OS

```
/dev/mmcblk2: PTUUID="4d70b4c9-01de-4b8e-b124-acbbefe548cb" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/mmcblk2p1: UUID="174D86ED7BB8DA8D" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="f714bd6f-e899-4fcf-9a9d-209b4b435187"
/dev/mmcblk1: PTUUID="8c824786-5d43-401e-a238-b29a6cb0bdc3" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/mmcblk1p1: UUID="328D-37EB" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="54a8e858-7df3-4a6d-bb07-475f6485e981"
/dev/mmcblk1p2: UUID="5f762552-5fd5-4908-a356-f17b1902db39" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8647d139-56d8-46c9-b8cc-65d6bc0988ae"
```

Then I have installed the Android, on the same mmcblk1p2, during installation I have chosen not to format, and full read-write. During installation I also skipped GRUB installation.

Then, I have configured inside `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, with this line:

```
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,2)'
linux /android-6.0-r3/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=generic_x86 SRC/android-6.0-r3 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode

initrd /android-6.0-r3/initrd.img
}
```

When GRUB is loaded, I can enter the Android menu entry, but then, it will just show the ANDROID silver logo animating, and that's it. Even after 10 minutes, nothing happens.

Earlier, I tried this GRUB script:

```
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,2)'
search --file --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5f762552-5fd5-4908-a356-f17b1902db39
linux /android-6.0-r3/kernel root=UUID=5f762552-5fd5-4908-a356-f17b1902db39 quiet      androidboot.hardware=generic_x86 SRC/android-6.0-r3 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode

initrd /android-6.0-r3/initrd.img
}
```

Appreciate if someone could point me if anything is not right about the grub entry list. Currently the location of the android installation is inside /:

```
$ sudo ls / -l
total 1392368
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 Sep  15 17:19 android-6.0-r3

# ls -l
total 8332
drwxrwx--x 25 affeirul affeirul    4096 Sep  15 17:27 data
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     1359021 Sep  15 17:18 initrd.img
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     5740976 Sep  15 17:18 kernel
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     1419637 Sep  15 17:18 ramdisk.img
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root        4096 Sep  15 17:19 system
```

Really appreciate any experts from here. Thank you.

Comment: If your Ubuntu install boots properly, but the Android does not, I'm afraid your question is off topic.

Comment: Hi sir.. thanks for responding.. i would like to have dual boot of ubuntu and androidx86.. so is it the title of my question is wrong??

Comment: @OrganicMarble This possibly on topic question was self-answered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for paying attention on my query.. actually I am still learning Ubuntu and GRUB..managed to resolve the thing by myself after changing the grub entry to this:

> `menuentry "Android-x86" {
>   set root='(hd0,2)'
>   linux /android-6.0-r3/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 SRC/android-6.0-r3 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode
>   initrd /android-6.0-r3/initrd.img
>   }`

Now the Android is booting up just fine..